# Erlang: How to convert Atom to String?

Tags: string, erlang, immutability

I want to convert from atom to string.

```
Input  =  'hello world'.
Output =  "hello world".
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is this Erlang or Elixir? In Elixir, text within single quotes is a character list, but in Erlang, text within single quotes is an atom.

Comment: Gotcha ! it should be atom to string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`atom_to_list`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#atom_to_list-1):

```
> atom_to_list('hello world').
"hello world"
```