# Erlang - How do I convert an atom to a be wrapped with ' " '?

Tags: erlang

For example, the atom:

`hello` would become `"hello"`

Due to being an immutability language, the string would be stored separately however.

Comment: In erlang, a double quoted string is a shortcut for creating a list of integers, where the integers in the list are the ascii codes of the characters.  Therefore, whenever you see a double quoted string, think LIST_OF_INTEGERS!  So, your question becomes, "How do I convert an atom to a list?".  Head to the [erl docs](https://erldocs.com/21.0/erts/erlang.html?i=1&search=atom_to#atom_to_list/1) and type in: `atom_to` and see what comes up => `atom_to_list: Returns a string corresponding to the text representation of Atom`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erlang : Convert Atom to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865898/erlang-convert-atom-to-string)

Answer (score 3):

`atom_to_list`

> Returns a string corresponding to the text representation of Atom, for
> example:

```
atom_to_list('Erlang').
"Erlang"
```

https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#atom_to_list-1